# Stopping media players in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an application in android which uses many mediaplayers from a service.

Seeking a way that pressing a button, stop the audio.

The problem is that I can not know the name of the media player is playing when I press the button.

Is there any way to stop all mediaplayers? or to detect the name of the mediaplayer is playing and stop it?

I appreciate any help
Thanks and regards

Comment: why do you need several mediaplayers?

Comment: to play audio in sequence, using setOnCompletionListener.

Comment: IMO, I think it is possible to do it with only one MediaPlayer. In my project I play videos in sequence with only one MediaPlayer.

Comment: @Lazy Ninja can you help me with the playback sequence with a single mediaplayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At most, you need two `MediaPlayer` objects. While one is playing, call `prepare` or `prepareAsync` on the other. After the 2nd finishes preparation (in `OnPreparedListener` if using async), call `setNextMediaPlayer` on the `MediaPlayer` object that is currently playing. If the current one has finished before preparation completed just go ahead and call `start` instead.

Be sure to call `release` in the `OnCompletionListener` for each player, and if there are more files to play simply call `setDataSource` and `prepare` (or `prepareAsync`) for the next media. You can continue this pattern indefinitely without using extraneous resources, and the playback should switch as seamlessly as Android is able to make it.